# regular expression to match contents other than opening tag

Tags: php, regex

Attempting to match contents of tag, with the exclusion of any other tag. I have some malformed html I'm trying to clean up.
Put simple:

```
    <td><ins>sample content</td>
    <td>other content</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>remaining</ins>other copy</td>
```

I'd like to capture "sample content", the html before it (`<td><ins>`), and the html after it, up to and exclude `</ins`>

I believe what I'm looking for is a negative look ahead, but I'm a little lost as to how this would work in PHP.

Comment: use php-tidy for malformed html

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not able to.

Comment: and what about `remaining`..it has no opening tag

Comment: `remaining` would be capture.

Comment: @onassar and you never mentioned that in your question..also do you want match any content which doesnt have a proper opening or closing tag!

Comment: In Regex, the carrot can be used to specify a "not": `[^a]` will match anything that's not `a`.

Comment: Thanks @jacob; I'm trying to not match a specific pattern (eg. </[a-z]+>)

Comment: Ohh, sorry I missed the last sentence of your question. You will need more than just regex to do this. It looks like you essentially want to create a parser. I suggest a shell script and use while read or, better yet, AWK (which will go line-by-line and allow you to search first for an opening tag then a closing one). Caveat: AWK is very powerful but also very complicated (the wikipedia page is actually quite helpful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK ).

Comment: Hmm. I think this can be done by regex. I have enough knowns and know exactly what I want to get.

Comment: Will you be looking specifically for `<ins>sample content</td>`?

Comment: for now, yeh. i think once i have a pattern down, i can inject some flexibility, but i know quite a bit about the contexts.

Comment: Hmm, well if you've got few of those phrases you need to match across several files, I would pump them into an array and loop thru them. And then you can just match via str_replace the exact phrase without invoking the regex engine (much less costly).

Comment: Well I'll need regex since the content with the `<ins>` tags is variable, no?

Comment: Oh, then you're not looking specifically for the whole phrase `<ins>sample content</td>`. Do you know what the unclosed opening tag is and do you know what parent closing tag that follows `some content`? (2 yes's, or 2 no's, or 1 yes and 1 no).

Comment: first capture: `sample content`. 2nd capture: `</td>...remaining`. 3rd capture: `other copy</td>`

Comment: That did not answer my question, and your method/order is incorrect.

Comment: I don't know what the unclosed opening tag is, no.

Comment: k, gimme a minute to write up an answer

Comment: You should use an HTML parser when parsing HTML - because HTML is very very tricky to get right in all corner cases

Comment: @onassar, I updated my answer (and tested it based on your sample code).

Comment: Hey @jacob, i'll take a look shortly. I was hoping to find a solution that was regex focused, so I'm not sure if I'll be able to use this. Looks like a regex solution may not be at hand though :(

Comment: @onassar, sadly as awesome as regex is, it cannot do this on its own.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't know what the unclosed opening tag is, you are creating a bare-bones parser.

You will need to loop over your content and stop every time you encounter an opening angle-bracket `<`. This REALLY should be done with **[AWK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK)**; however if you must use PHP, you would do something like this

```
<?php

    $file = file_get_contents('path/to/file');
    $file = preg_replace( '/[\n\r\t]/' , '' , $file );

    $pieces = explode( '<' , $file );
    if ( !$pieces[0] ) array_shift($pieces);

    /* Given your example code, $pieces looks like this
    $pieces = array(
        [0] => 'td>',
        [1] => 'ins>sample content',
        [2] => '/td>',
        [3] => 'td>other content',
        [4] => '/td>',
        [5] => '/tr>',
        [6] => 'tr>',
        [7] => 'td>remaining',
        [8] => '/ins>other copy',
        [9] => '/td>'
    );
    */

    $openers = array();//$openers = [];
    $closers = array();//$closers = [];
    $brokens = array();//$brokens = [];

    for ( $i = 0 , $count = count($pieces) ; $i < $count ; $i++ ) {
        //grab everything essentially between the brackets
        $tag = strstr( $pieces[$i] , '>' , TRUE );
        $oORc = strpos( $pieces[$i] , '/' );

        if ( $oORc !== FALSE ) {
            //store this for later (and maintain $pieces' index)
            $closers[$i] = $tag;
            $elm = str_replace( '/' , '' , $tag );
            if ( ( $oIndex = array_search( $elm , $openers ) ) && count($openers) != count($closers) ) {
                //more openers than closers ==> broken pair
                $brokens[$oIndex] = $pieces[$oIndex];
                $cIndex = array_search( $tag, $closers );
                $brokens[$cIndex] = $pieces[$cIndex];
                //remove the unpaired elements from the 2 arrays so count works
                unset( $openers[$oIndex] , $closers[$cIndex] );
            }
        } else {
            $openers[$i] = $tag;
        }//fi

    }//for

    print_r($brokens);

?>
```

The index in `$brokens` is the index from `$pieces` where the malformed html appeared and its value is the offending tag and its content:

```
$brokens = Array(
    [1] => ins>sample content
    [8] => /ins>other copy
);
```

**Caveat** This does not account for self-closing tags like `<br />` or `<img />` (but that's why you should use one of the many software apps that already exist for this).